# Is a precision/F-score of 10% to be expected on using SVM as image classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

As my learning project in Machine Learning I am trying to use an SVM (Support Vector Machine) to classify different images of domino tiles. I am basing this project heavily on this project https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-face-recognition-py which I have re-created and understood as well as gotten a precision/F1 of about 70% (if I recall correctly). I am using much of the same code in my project.

In my project I have 28 different folders and in each 100 different 100x100px images of domino tiles(i.e. 2800 images). The domino tiles are photographed with different background, different zoom and different rotation. These images could be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/wallcloud/photographs-of-28-different-domino-tiles

I have tested:

- All sorts of combinations of C, gamma, kernels on the SVC and found the optimal combination
- PCA with different number of components (500 seems to be an optimal number)
- Using LabelEncoders (no difference)
- Different test sizes (0.1 seems to be optimal)
- Cropping images (improves the score), using filters on the images (worsens the score) as well as making them B/W (worsens the score).

With all this I still can't make my score to exceed 10% which is VERY far from what the Scikit-Learn project achieves on the faces.

According to feedback I have received from experienced ML-engineers, the data should be sufficient to classify the dominoes. I was suspicious whether SVM:s would actually be suitable as an image classifier but as the Scikit-Learn project uses it I would assume this SHOULD work as well. I am sure a CNN would work great for this but that is not my question.

When I output the "eigenfaces" for the domino tiles they appear as a "motion blur" which seems to have to do with the dominos being rotated. This could be a potential reason (the Scikit-Learn images of faces are not rotated). I would, however, expect the model pick up on the dots of the domino tiles better but that assumption may be erronous.

My question is now:

Q: Is my score of 10% to be expected considering the amount, and type, of data and using SVM as a classifier - or am I missing out on something crucial?

### My python code

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm, metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
#from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import preprocessing 
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
import os # Working with files and folders
from PIL import Image # Image processing
from PIL import ImageFilter

### 
### Data can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s5f38k4l2on5mba/AACNQgXuw1edwEb6oO1w3CfOa?dl=0
### 


start = time.time()
rootdir = os.getcwd()

image_file = 'images.npy'
key_file = 'keys.npy'

def predict_me(image_file_name, scaler, pca):
  pm = Image.open(image_file_name)
  pm = pm.resize([66,66])
  a = np.array(pm.convert('L')).reshape(1,-1)
  #a = np.array(pm.resize([66,66]).convert('L')).reshape(1,-1)) # array 66x66
  a = scaler.transform(a)
  a = pca.transform(a)
  return classifier.predict(a)

def crop_image(im, sq_size):
  new_width = sq_size
  new_height = sq_size
  width, height = im.size   # Get dimensions 
  left = (width - new_width)/2
  top = (height - new_height)/2
  right = (width + new_width)/2
  bottom = (height + new_height)/2
  imc = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
  return imc 

#def filter_image(im):
  # All filter makes it worse
  #imf = im.filter(ImageFilter.EMBOSS)
  #return imf

def provide_altered_images(im):
  im_list = [im]
  im_list.append(im.rotate(90))
  im_list.append(im.rotate(180))
  im_list.append(im.rotate(270))
  return im_list

if (os.path.exists(image_file) and os.path.exists(key_file)):
  print("Loading existing numpy's")
  pixel_arr = np.load(image_file)
  key = np.load(key_file)
else:
  print("Creating new numpy's")  
  key_array = []
  pixel_arr = np.empty((0,66*66), "uint8")

  for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('data'):
    dir_name = subdir.split("/")[-1]    
    if "x" in dir_name:
      for file in files:
        if ".DS_Store" not in file:
          im = Image.open(os.path.join(subdir, file))
          if im.size == (100,100):  
            use_im = crop_image(im,66) # Most images are shot from too far away. This removes portions of it.
            #use_im = filter_image(use_im) # Filters image, but does no good at all
            im_list = provide_altered_images(use_im) # Create extra data with 3 rotated images of every image
            for alt_im in im_list:
              key_array.append(dir_name)  # Each image here is still the same as directory name
              numpied_image = np.array(alt_im.convert('L')).reshape(1,-1) # Converts to grayscale
              #Image.fromarray(np.reshape(numpied_image,(-1,100)), 'L').show()
              pixel_arr = np.append(pixel_arr, numpied_image, axis=0)
          im.close()

  key = np.array(key_array)
  np.save(image_file, pixel_arr)
  np.save(key_file, key)



# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=10, kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced') # gamma and C from tests
#le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
#le.fit(key)
#transformed_key = le.transform(key)
transformed_key = key


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(pixel_arr, transformed_key, test_size=0.1,random_state=7)

#scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

pca = PCA(n_components=500, svd_solver='randomized', whiten=True)
# Fit on training set only.
#scaler.fit(X_train)
pca.fit(X_train)

# Apply transform to both the training set and the test set.
#X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
#X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train)
X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)


print ("Fit classifier")
classifier = classifier.fit(X_train_pca, y_train)
print ("Score = " + str(classifier.score(X_test_pca, y_test)))

# Now predict the value of the domino on the test data:
expected = y_test

print ("Predicting")
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test_pca)

print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n"
      % (classifier, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)))
#print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted, labels  =list(set(key))))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

### Output (the last being the time in seconds)

```
Score = 0.09830205540661305
Predicting
Classification report for classifier SVC(C=10, cache_size=200, class_weight='balanced', coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma=0.001, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False):
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

  b'0x0'       0.22      0.44      0.30        27
  b'1x0'       0.24      0.23      0.24        43
  b'1x1'       0.15      0.12      0.13        49
  b'2x0'       0.13      0.15      0.14        34
  b'2x1'       0.16      0.16      0.16        44
  b'2x2'       0.02      0.03      0.03        36
  b'3x0'       0.05      0.06      0.05        36
  b'3x1'       0.05      0.05      0.05        42
  b'3x2'       0.08      0.09      0.08        46
  b'3x3'       0.15      0.16      0.15        50
  b'4x0'       0.15      0.15      0.15        40
  b'4x1'       0.07      0.05      0.06        42
  b'4x2'       0.02      0.02      0.02        41
  b'4x3'       0.09      0.08      0.09        49
  b'4x4'       0.11      0.10      0.11        39
  b'5x0'       0.18      0.12      0.14        42
  b'5x1'       0.00      0.00      0.00        38
  b'5x2'       0.02      0.02      0.02        43
  b'5x3'       0.07      0.08      0.07        36
  b'5x4'       0.07      0.04      0.05        51
  b'5x5'       0.11      0.14      0.12        42
  b'6x0'       0.03      0.03      0.03        37
  b'6x1'       0.07      0.10      0.08        31
  b'6x2'       0.03      0.03      0.03        33
  b'6x3'       0.09      0.07      0.08        45
  b'6x4'       0.02      0.03      0.03        30
  b'6x5'       0.16      0.19      0.17        37
  b'6x6'       0.10      0.08      0.09        36

   micro avg       0.10      0.10      0.10      1119
   macro avg       0.09      0.10      0.10      1119
   weighted avg       0.10      0.10      0.10      1119


115.74487614631653
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the reasons is that you should not give your raw images as the input of your SVM classifier directly, even if you applied a PCA. You should whether compute features which describe the shape, contrast and colors of your images and put them in the classifier, or use a **CNN**. CNNs were made to classify images, and there structures automatically compute features for the images.

Comment: Thanks. A CNN is out of the question now (mainly because I am personally exploring shallow algos to see limitations etc). As for your other part of the answer, how would I go by to "compute features which describe the shape..."? In the domino tiles there are those "dots" on the domino tiles. With that knowledge at hand, is there a way to use that? What should I be looking for/google to get closer?